# Not implemented when use parameterized query in Pentaho CDE with Redshift JDBC

Tags: datasource, pentaho, amazon-redshift, parameterized-query, pentaho-cde

I have a problem using Pentaho 6 CE and Amazon Redshift as my datasource to create dashboard with parameterized query.

When I use parameter in datasource like

```
where city_id in (${cityid})
```

It returns an error (Not Implemented) and the console log show me this

[Not Implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiah4.jpg)

But if I hardcode the parameter value it works and shows the diagram with proper result. I've tried two different versions of Redshift JDBC (4.0 and 4.1) but still not working.

Comment: What do you mean by hardcoding the parameter value?

Comment: I mean like this `where city_id in (1,2,3)`